# Screen receiver not working within my Service

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to get my Screen ON/OFF to work on my Service, but so far no luck.

The goal is: Get the LED lights ( softkeys ) to go out when the screen goes OFF and Softkey light to turn ON when the screen goes back ON with the values the user inputed on my app ( you will see the TextXLActivity.getledC() which gets the Int from the main activity )

On my main activity i can control the LED lights without any problem, with a SeekBar and so on. Only thing not working is really the Receiver/Service

Now when I go to settings, applications, running services, my App is not listed anywhere, I am affraid my Service isn't starting at all, and maybe that is the problem here.

Here is my Receiver:

```
package com.test.xl;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private boolean screenOff;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        screenOff = true;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        screenOff = false;
    }
    Intent i = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
    i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
    context.startService(i);
}



}
```

And here my Service:

```
package com.test.xl;




import com.sonyericsson.illumination.IlluminationIntent;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class UpdateService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

}
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    boolean screenOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("screen_state", false);
    if (!screenOn) {

        {
            Intent led = new Intent(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_START_LED);
            led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.test.xl");
            led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
            led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, TestXLActivity.getledC());
            startService(led);
        }

    } else {


        Intent led = new Intent(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_STOP_LED);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.test.xl");
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        startService(led);

    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
```

This is a Test app I started to try and understand the Receiver/Service "relation", any help would be appreciated! ;)

I also noticed that my Service forces me to implement this lines:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

I followed a tutorial on how to get my service to interact with the Receiver and the source code there had nothing like that at the end, any guesses?

Best regards

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.xl"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.illumination.permission.ILLUMINATION"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestXLActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <receiver android:name=".ScreenReceiver">
 <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action..ACTION_SCREEN_ON" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Edit: 
Here is the source code where the error appears (startService(led)):

```
package com.test.xl;

import com.sonyericsson.illumination.IlluminationIntent;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private boolean screenOff;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

        Intent led = new Intent(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_STOP_LED);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.test.xl");
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        startService(led);
        screenOff = true;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {

        Intent led = new Intent(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_START_LED);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.test.xl");
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, TestXLActivity.getledC());
        startService(led);
        screenOff = false;
    }

}
```

}

**NEW CODE**

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private boolean screenOff;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

        Intent led = new Intent(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_STOP_LED);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.test.xl");
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        context.startService(led);
        screenOff = true;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {

        int ledC = TestXLActivity.getledC();

        Intent led = new Intent(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_START_LED);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.test.xl");
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, ledC);
        context.startService(led);
        screenOff = false;
    }

}
```

.

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {

private ScreenReceiver mReceiver = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    if(mReceiver != null)mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

I think you problem is that your BroadcastReceiver mReceiver does not survive after the onCreate method of your service. Furthermore you are not declare it right. If I was you I would do something like this:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {

private ScreenReceiver mReceiver = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    if(mReceiver != null)mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    *** NOTE HERE THAT I AM OVERRIDING THE ONSTART AS AN INT NOT VOID***

    .... do your stuff here....

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Now there is another problem with your approach. You are declaring and instantiating your receiver in the service's onCreate method and then you are starting the service AGAIN from within onReceive method of your receiver. This is not the way android services work.
The correct approach is to instantiate and register your receiver from the onCreate method of your service and start the service from another point of your application, for example if it is an app-widget you can do this from the onUpdate method of the WidgetProvider or from some Activity's onCreate method.

So your code should be as follow:

1. Your receviver:

   ```
   public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       private boolean screenOff;

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
               screenOff = true;
           } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
               screenOff = false;
           }

           ... Do your stuff here for screen on or off ....
           ... AND DO NOT START A SERVICE FROM HERE ....
       }
   }
   ```
2. Your service:

   ```
   public class UpdateService extends Service {

       private ScreenReceiver mReceiver = null;

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           super.onCreate();
           // register receiver that handles screen on and screen off logic
           IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
           filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
           if(mReceiver != null)mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
           registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
       }

       @Override
       public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
           NOTE HERE THAT I AM OVERRIDING THE ONSTART AS AN INT NOT VOID

           .... YOU DON'T HAVE TO DO SOMETHING HERE EXCEPT FROM SOME ....
           .... INITIALIZATION CODE ...

           return Service.START_STICKY;
       }

       @Override
       public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public void onDestroy() {
           UnregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
           super.onDestroy();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Your Activity or other code point:

   startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));

What happens here is this:

When the startService executes your service is instantiated and the onCreate method executes in which the receiver is registered and starts monitoring for Intents. Then the onStart method of the service is called and it returns START_STICKY which means that the service will be restarted if terminated from the system and thus the receiver will be registered again and so on. BTW whenever your service terminating the onDestroy method will be called and the receiver will be unregistered (which is a very goog thing to do).

Now you have a service run all the time ready to receive notifications from the system.

If you wish to terminate the service at some point, simply call the

```
context.stopService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));
```

I don't really know Android services in depth but this technique works very well with my service which hosts a BroadcastReceiver and a ContentObserver at the same time.

***EDIT BASED ON YOUR NEW PROGRESS***

Ok now it seems that we are getting somewhere. I can see in your onReceive method

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        Intent led = new Intent(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_STOP_LED);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.test.xl");
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        context.startService(led);
        screenOff = true;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {

        int ledC = TestXLActivity.getledC();

        Intent led = new Intent(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_START_LED);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.test.xl");
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, ledC);
        context.startService(led);
        screenOff = false;
    }
}
```

You are declaring an intent led and you are using it to start a service, but you are not specifying which service to start. I think you are missing something like led.setClass. But in order to clear things a little bit let's modify the onReceive like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent led = new Intent(context, your_led_service_name.class);
    led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.test.xl");

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        led.addAction(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_STOP_LED);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        context.startService(led);
        screenOff = true;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        int ledC = TestXLActivity.getledC();
        led.addAction(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_START_LED);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, ledC);
        context.startService(led);
        screenOff = false;
    }
}
```

and see how it goes now...

SECOND EDIT

Ok I don't know anything about Sony Ericsson Illumination API but based on your code you may need to change the onReceive as follows:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    IlluminationIntent led = new IlluminationIntent(??);
    //Note: In place of ?? you may need your context on nothing at all
    //it depends on sony's API.

    led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "com.test.xl");

    led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_ID, IlluminationIntent.VALUE_BUTTON_2);
    //This is only needed once...

    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
        led.addAction(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_STOP_LED);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        screenOff = true;
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
        int ledC = TestXLActivity.getledC();
        led.addAction(IlluminationIntent.ACTION_START_LED);
        led.putExtra(IlluminationIntent.EXTRA_LED_COLOR, ledC);
        screenOff = false;
    }

    context.startService(led);
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Damn this surely sounds like something i should really pay attention to. Thank you very much for your time and patience explaining me all this! Really appreciate it. I will now try to change my code and see what I get. Thank alot!

Comment: You mean there that i should put my code to control the LED lights on the Receiver and not on the service? I am getting confused now.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I mean. What you are doing now is not right. You are declaring a receiver in a service which is NEVER started. That is, your onCreate method of your service never gets called from some point in order to register the receiver, furthermore if it will run then the receiver will start the service again which in turn it will re-register the receiver which will start the service again and so on. It will be an endless loop: SERVICE --> RECEIVER --> SERVICE --> RECEIVER ...

Comment: I did it, Now i am getting an error on startService(led); Eclipse asks me if i want to create that method o.O

Comment: startService is a methog of the context object. You need to call it like this: context.startService(led); But I am warning you, if you are going to use your code as it is in your post it will not work as expected...

Comment: what you mean? I changed my Receiver and Service codes to what you provided me, why wouldnt it work now?

Comment: In your edited code you are still calling startService from the receiver. If you are corrected them in your project then it will work...

Comment: Ok something happens when the screen goes OFF, the LEDs turn ON, and when the screen goes ON nothing happens, they just stay ON. uploaded the NEW CODE on my first post. Check it out

Comment: I am also getting an error here "startService(new Intent(context, UpdateService.class));" on the word context cannot be resolved to a variable :/

Comment: you need to replace context with your actual Context. If you are calling this from an activity then you should write startService(new Intent(this, UpdateService.class));

Comment: Yeah i ended up figuring out, i did that, started the App and still there is nothing showing on my running services. This is not working somehow :/

Comment: I have got no LedService class, I am running an external .Jar from sony which controls the LEDs "import com.sonyericsson.illumination.IlluminationIntent;"

Comment: I will give it a try later when i get the chance to,thank you

Comment: just tried it out, I am getting erros on putExtra, startService, everywhere :/